# Dimmig universal motor speed control IGBT or Triac?

Tags: motor, triac, igbt

I want to control speed of 220VAC universal motor (Grinder) using Microcontroller, which method is better in comparison??

1. Using Triac which zero-crossing detection and control pulse generation for each cycle
2. Using retifier and capacitor to make High voltage DC and use PWM to drive IGBT
   For me IGBT seem more easy to control because I can use high frequency PWM withour caring of AC zero-crossing. And my control loop can run faster provide more stable close-loop system.

Comment: You know you don't necessarily need a MCU, you can use a RC to control the firing rate of a diac into the gate of your triac, like how the dimmers or celling fan speed controllers work. but ofc if you want to control the flow digitally, that's a different story

Comment: @AliKavoosi well, I need to control speed corespoding to speed readed from sensor.